# How to prevent page reload when clicking on an anchor tag with link within page?

Tags: html

I'm using a HTML anchor tag for a "back to top" link in the footer of my web page:

`<a href="#top" class="footer__top">Back to top</a>`

At the top of the page I inserted another anchor tag in `<HEAD>`:

`<a id="#top"></a>`

Clicking on the footer anchor link causes the page to scroll up as intended, but is there a way to simply scroll to top (using HTML) without refreshing the page?

For context, search results are being displayed so when the page refreshes, the results are lost.

I found a possible solution using Javascript (see below - it scrolls to top without refreshing the page) but this causes other issues for me (search input field becomes frozen and user cannot enter more terms), so I'm asking whether there's a solution using HTML:

```
  $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: A simple anchor link to an id does not cause a page refresh. There must be something else going on that you haven't shown if it does. You have also exhausted what can be achieved with HTML alone, an anchor to an id.

Comment: I had read somewhere (or thought I read) that clicking an anchor tag linking within a page causes the page to refresh. But if you say it doesn't then I'll have to look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll to top of the page(your div is on top)
You can use below Javascript syntax to achieve this.

```
window.scrollto(0,0) // (0,0) being the location
```